# Задать размер шрифта на веб-странице такого же размера как в Word

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть некоторый веб-сервис, генерирующий [при помощи WkHtmlToPdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) PDF файл из html-страницы.

Одно из требований к документу (а это некоторый формуляр, утверждённый госорганом), чтобы документ выглядел так же, как и распечатка из MS Word.

И вот тут я упёрся в одну проблему. Документ набран 12тым шрифтом, я на автопилоте написал:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>

body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- page 1 -->
<p style="text-align:left;">УТВЕРЖДЕН</p>
...
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- page 2 -->
```

И... споткнулся о то, что размер шрифта при распечатке не соответствует размеру шрифта, распечатанного из Ms Word.

В принципе, можно попробовать подобрать за несколько итераций поменял - распечатал - сравнил некий магический коэффициент, но вообще – как решать такую проблему правильно?

Comment: Ппоробую угадать: что если `font-size: 12px`? Возможно, в сочетании с параметром `--dpi 72`

Comment: 12px пробовал, шрифт ещё мельче становится, а вот dpi -- мысль любопытная. Ща погуглю, куда это прописывать и попробую.

Comment: Эх не, у меня dpi почему-то ни на что не влияет, странности

Comment: Почему-то мой wkhtmltopdf вообще все связанные с размером опции игнорирует. На гитхабе есть такие жалобы, похоже забаговано всё

Comment: Хотя скачивание другой версии и метод научного тыка привели меня к `--zoom 1.25`

Comment: @andreymal Это влияет только на высоту шрифта (при `font-size: 15pt` на просвет одинаковая высота букв) -- тот самый магический коэффициент, который можно найти (почему такой, кстати?), но расстояние между буквами несколько иное.

Comment: Боюсь, такого же расстояния между буквами никак не достичь, просто потому что движки рендеринга шрифтов в вебките и в ворде разные и с этим останется только смириться. "Почему такой" - я тупо нарисовал div с width:21cm и он в готовом pdf оказался в 1.25 раза короче ширины A4 :D

Comment: Хотя, возможно, можно с параметром dpi поиграться - у меня при его изменении буквы немного "дрожат", может где-то есть значение, которое позволит добиться совпадения с вордом)) Но это всё действительно магия с костылями, так себе решение

Comment: Но ведь это зависит еще и от настроек принтера. В драйверах можно настроить масштабирование, или заставить документ "вписаться" в страницу, с автоматическим подбором масштаба. Мне кажется нужно не в pdf конвертировать сразу в docx. Тогда точно будет одинаково.

Comment: @andreymal, "Боюсь, такого же расстояния между буквами никак не достичь", а если поиграться с "letter-spacing"?

Answer (score 1):

font-size: 12pt; - Вам использовать ни в коем случаи нельзя. Поскольку данная величина зависит от плотностей пикселей, а она у разных браузерах разная (Считается по разному для Хрома и Сафари так точно ). Поэтому смотрите в сторону px em rem

Comment: Хочу дополнить, что единица измерения `pt` считается [устаревшей](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units), если прям хотите использовать аналогичный подход, то можете [конвертировать px в pt](https://i.imgur.com/4ePjk9G.png)